# Signed assembly not being recognised

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, csla, vs-web-site-project

I've converted a Visual Studio 2005 Website Project into a Web Application Project by creating a new web app project then copying in all the files and using the 'Convert to Web Application' option. I've added all the same references from the Website project to the web app project. After that I'm down to 1 error in the compiler and it's due to a referenced project.

```
Error   8
The type 'CSLA.ReadOnlyCollectionBase' is defined in an assembly 
that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'CSLA, Version=1.3.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1ebd9544eb4fe327'.  C:\Development\WebApp\WebUI
\Page1.aspx.cs  154 24  WebApp
```

I've checked and there is a reference to the project and it has a class file for ReadOnlyCollectionBase. The DLL is signed, could this have something to do with it? Also I've copied the web.config directly from the website project into the web app project.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means that you are referencing a dll which uses CSLA and so you need to add a reference to CSLA on that project. This is probably your web project.

Comment: It wasn't that because I already had all of the references in the web project. This error is related to the fact that CSLA 1.3 doesn't support running under the Visual Studio Development Server due to the identity principal, a known bug from microsoft. It works fine running under IIS so that's what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think that this would be a bug with authentication. It is a old version of CSLA though. I would make sure that the CSLA assembly is added as a reference to the web application and exists in the bin directory (Set the Copy Local property on the reference).

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))